# Github actions sed -i "s/" not escaping properly "//" in url

Tags: github-actions

I have such silly issue that I can't get working. I am using GitHub actions and I want to replace some ulr.
My `sed` looks like this:
 `sed -i "s/${{ inputs.original-variable }}` for `inputs.original-variable` i want to use such url: `'wss://mm-websocket.mydomain.com'` but every time this is running it is not properly escaping and i do get this error `sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to s'` `"s/wss://mm-websocket.mydomain.com`

I was trying to use `const` and replace whole const with a string not string itslef, but still did not work for me

Also how i can run my ci job localy will `gh run file.yml` work?

Edit:
Before sed I have `'wss://mm-websocket.mydomains.com/'`
After sed I want to have `wss://mm-websocket.mydomain.com`

Actual step in `.yml` file

```
original-variable: wss://mm-websocket.mydomains.com/
destination-variable: wss://mm-websocket.mydomain.com/
file-path: 'apps/app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts'
```

actual replace step

```
run: |
  destinationVariable=${{ inputs.destination-variable }}
  parsedDestinationVariable="${destinationVariable//\//\\/}"
  sed -i "s/${{ inputs.original-variable }}/$parsedDestinationVariable/" "${{ inputs.file-path }}"
```

Comment: Could you please add an example of what is the expected result of the sed command to the question? Something like: `before sed command` and `after sed command`.

Comment: added before and after sed results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `sed` for URLs, using forward slashes `/` could cause problems, try using a different deliminator like `@`

```
sed -i "s@${{ inputs.original-variable }}@$parsedDestinationVariable@" "${{ inputs.file-path }}"
```